# Animate image sequence on React Native

Tags: react-native

I have an animation consisting of a sequence of images: `image01.png`, `image02.png`, `image03.png`, etc. How do I get these to animate continuously on React Native?

Comment: You can checkout Animated and Layout Animation react-native provides.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try with libraries:

- https://github.com/madsleejensen/react-native-image-sequence
- https://github.com/remobile/react-native-image-animation

First is more more efficient, second is in pure javascript. Another way is to implement it on your own way, like here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9280

It should looks like this

```
export default class Animation extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.images = [
            require('./img_01.png'),
            require('./img_02.png'),
            require('./img_03.png'),
        ];
        this.next = this.next.bind(this);
        this.state = {index: 0};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.next();
    }

    next() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({index: (this.state.index+1)%3});
            this.next();
        }, 300);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Image
              source={this.images[this.state.index]}
              style={styles.image}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create functional component

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Image } from "react-native";

const currentSourceImages = [
    require('./image01.png'),
    require('./image02.png'),
    require('./image03.png')
];

const CurrentSourceIndicator = () => {
    const [currentSourceIndex, setCurrentSourceIndex] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
        const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
                let index = currentSourceIndex + 1;
                if (index >= currentSourceImages.length) {
                    index = 0;
                }
                setCurrentSourceIndex(index);
            }, 1000);

            return () => {
                clearTimeout(timeout);
            };
    }, [currentSourceIndex]);

    return (
        <Image
            source={currentSourceImages[currentSourceIndex]}
            style={styles.currentSourceImage} />
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    currentSourceImage: {
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        resizeMode: 'contain'
    },
});

export default CurrentSourceIndicator;
```