# Animate image sequence on React Native using Animated.timing()

Tags: animation, react-native

Is it possible to animate a sequence of images: image01.png, image02.png, image03.png, etc. using React Native Animated API?

I've tried to use timer for this as it is described here: [Animate image sequence on React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38580622/animate-image-sequence-on-react-native)

But on Android animation is too slow and twitchy.

I'm trying to use `useNativeDriver` property of `Animated.timing()` method. But seems like it's not a proper way of playing a sequence of images in `<Animated.Image/>` block.

Comment: Yes you can, check this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations.html#composing-animations

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I've already checked this part of RN docs and tried to apply it.

But looks like if I have for example an array of 10 images, which I want to show one by one during 2 seconds, I actually can't use array index in Animated block and gradually change it from 0 to 9. Although when I'm trying to change the opacity of image instead of the array index, animation with opacity works.

Comment: If you can paste the code in gist and share it, it would be more helpful.

Comment: I've already done what i need by using lottie lib. Thanks for your respond